# spark program using maven in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am new to spark. I am using intelliJ Idea with maven integration for running spark examples.
But I am facing problems in run a simple hello world program using spark and java class.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.4.0</hadoop.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

And I am getting error on these lines

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
```

Comment: It may help if you include more details about the errors you're getting.

Comment: red line appears under apache and it says cannot resolve error

Comment: Are you directly connected to the internet (or behind a corporate proxy) , did the dependency get resolved in the POM ? , can you run mvn clean compile and report what you get as error ?